# SVG files and ExpressJS

Tags: html, express, svg

Right now I am trying to load an SVG file in express' version of HTML.

Here is what the HTML looks like

```
`<button><a href="#" target="_self">Text<img src="../public/assets/facebook.svg" width="100px"></a></button>`
```

It is showing the default image where the image can't be loaded.

I am not sure what this means and why it isn't loading though I am sure I have the path correct.

Comment: Why are you sure the path is correct? Have you tried a png instead?

Comment: Chances are the file path is incorrect. Have you tried accessing it directly in your browser?